# Flutter Doctor Error:-X Android SDK file not found: adb

Tags: flutter

[image]

X Android SDK file not found: adb.

While Running Flutter Doctor it is showing error like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether platform-tools are installed or not.

`adb` is included in the Android SDK Platform-Tools package. You can download this package with the SDK Manager, which installs it at `android_sdk/platform-tools/`.

Comment: or just with command like `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-31"` as [documented](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager#install_packages)

Answer (score 0):

For me, Mac Catalina automatically tend to remove adb file. So set the security in mac preferences and open Android Studio using 'Open' option.

But if you already removed adb file, you have to replace Android Platform-tools again. Hope this help!